# How to "save as" a layer creating new data files, with QGIS 3.4?

Tags: qgis

With QGIS 2 you could right-click on a layer; choose "save as"; and create a new layer based on new data files that would thus be created (as contrasted with "Duplicate", which would create a new layer based on the same old data files.)

With QGIS 3.4.4 I see "Copy Layer", which I can then "Paste", but that seems to create a new layer with the same name and based on the same old data files.

QGIS 3 also offers "Duplicate Layer", but that also creates a new layer based on the same old data files.

So how do we now create a new layer based on a new set of data files?

Comment: посредством экспорта...

Comment: Right-click the layer and go to `Export > Save Feature As...` which I believe is what @Cyril meant in Russian :)

Comment: Yes, all right, Joseph   :-)...

Comment: You are a bit unclear, are you trying to save as (creating a new hard copy of existing file)  or create a new set of data file (empty new file) ?

Comment: Yes, that does what I wanted. Thank you! (Are we supposed to say thank you in this forum?)

Comment: If @Cyril can convert his post into an answer, you'll be able to accept it by clicking the faded green tick to show your problem has been solved.

Comment: All right, Joseph, let's not break the rules...

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't find the faded green tick.

Comment: The green bird should be on your left side of the answer under the number indicating the number of votes cast for the answer, for example 2...

Answer (score 2):

To create a new layer based on a new set of data files, perform the following actions:

1) click the left mouse button to make the layer active;

2) click the right mouse button from the active menu to select Save Features As...

See picture

[image]

Comment: It seems odd that some of your menu options are in English, and others are in another language (Greek?). Is that a bug?

Comment: No, it's a combination of English and Russian language, apparently when i install QGIS, I decided to pull to the English language, after all, very lazy, there's a lot of bugs, I'm used to :-)...Installed from the official website under Windows